# Use regex inside osgi bundles

Tags: osgi, equinox

we are using osgi based on eclipse equinox.
During the developement the packages/bundels are built with a `-dev-SNAPSHOT` version.

But after a relase the version is changed to e.g. `-v3.1`

So inside the config.ini file I would like to replace the specific version with a something similiar to a regular expresion.

```
osgi.bundles=\
com.example.important.bundle-dev-SNAPHOT.jar@start,\
...
```

How can I realize this?

Thank you in advance

Comment: You might want to take a look at bndtools, there you never have to worry about these issues since it is mostly automated.

Comment: I am using the gradle plugin(https://github.com/bndtools/bnd/tree/master/biz.aQute.bnd.gradle#gradle-plugin-for-non-bnd-workspace-builds)
Unfortunately I don't know what's your point?

Comment: If you switch to the bnd launcher you do not have to maintain versions since they are automatically generated from the dependency information. You specify the initial requirements in a bndrun file, resolve, and the rest is taken  care of.